# Is the BGQ spectral sequence functorial with respect to morphisms of finite Tor-dimension?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

It is well known that the BGQ (Brown-Gersten-Quillen) spectral sequence for the G-theory of a Noetherian scheme of finite Krull-dimension is contravariant with respect to flat morphisms.
My question is, is this spectral sequence also contravariant with respect to morphisms of finite Tor-dimension in general?
The motivation for this question is my attempt to show that for an algebraic 3-fold $X$,the filtration by codimension of support for coherent sheaves associated to the BGQ spectral sequence yields an exact sequence $0\rightarrow A^2(X)\rightarrow G_0(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus Cl(X)\rightarrow 0$.